# Translating statement into General Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a question from Kleene's Mathematical Logic that I am struggling to answer.

'Every liberal advocates changes. Some conservatives favour no one who advocates changes. Therefore, some conservatives favour no liberal.' (Kleene, 1967, 147).

My solution is as follows.
Every $x$ is a liberal, and every $y$ is a conservative. Every x advocates change $(Cy)$ and some y favour no-one who advocates change $\neg (Cx)$.

$\forall x (Cx) , \exists y(\neg Cy) \therefore \exists y(\neg Cx)$

I think this is right?

EDIT: 
Okay, so I know that the first premise is $\forall x(Lx \to Ax)$, or, for all $x$, such that $x$ is a (L)iberal, $x$ (A)dvocates change.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You have to translate every statement individually.

1st premise) Every liberal advocates changes.

> "for every $x$, if $x$ is Liberal, then $x$ Advocate changes".

2nd premise) Some conservatives favour no one who advocates changes.

> "there is some $y$ that is a Conservative and for every $z$, if $z$ Advocate changes, then $y$ does not Favour $z$".

Conclusion) Therefore, some conservatives favour no liberal.

> "there is some $w$ that is Conservative and for every $u$, if $u$ is a Liberal, then $w$ does not Favour $u$".

Comment: So, ∀x(Lx -> Ax), ∃y(Cy -> ~F(y, z) -> Az), ∴ Cz -> ~F(y, x)? I feel my conclusion is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You can't just stipulate that $x$'s will be used for liberals, and $y$'s for conservatives. All variables are assumed to be objects of one and the same domain.

So, what you need to do is use predicates $L(x)$ for '$x$ is a liberal' and $C(x)$ for '$x$ is a conservative.  Of course, you just proposed to use $C(x)$ for '$x$ advocates change', but for that you could use $A(x)$ instead.

Also, for the favouring, you want to use a $2$-place predicate $F(x,y)$ that means '$x$ favours $y$'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If both liberals and conservatives are under the same domain, then how do I express the favouring as a 2-place predicate? As in, what is the other variable? If I allow no-one to be variable y, then how do I express the conclusion? 

∀x(Lx -> Cx), ∃x(Ax -> F(x, y) -> Cy) ∴ ∃y(Ax -> F(x, y) -> Cx)

If I'm correct, that reads all x who are liberal favour change, some x who are conservative favour no y who advocates change. I am struggling to do the conclusion based off of this though, and I'm not even sure that first premise is correct, let alone the second.

Comment: @Hangdog First, it's always a good idea to add these further thought to your original post, so everyone can respond to your latest work.  Anyway, assuming you use $A(x)$ for '$x$ advocates change', your first premise should be $\forall x (L(x) \to A(x))$.  Finally, and to get to your real question: for the second  premise, and the conclusion: you will need to introduce a second quantifier for the second variable.

Comment: I have updated the post as per your advice. Having ∀x(L(x) → A(x)) as the first premise, I will stick to having x work for conservatives as well, but introduce a new variable & quantifier for no-one, let that be y, so ∃x ∀y C(x) & F(x, ~y) → A(y). That would translate to some x are conservative and favour no y who advocates change?

Comment: @Hangdog Close!  First, note that you never want any operators inside predicates, so you don;t want something like $F(x,\neg y)$. Instead, use $\neg F(x,y)$ to make the claim that $x$ does not favour $y$.  Second, make sure to use parentheses: $(C(x) \land \neg F(x,y)) \to A(y)$ means something different than $C(x) \land (\neg F(x,y) \to A(y))$. Finally, note that $\neg F(x,y) \to A(y)$  means that *if* $x$ does not favour $y$, then $y$ does not advocate change ... think about that: is that what you want?

Comment: @Hangdog Also, I took the liberty to edit your post and typeset your formulas, so please take a look so that you know how to do that.

Comment: Why the downvote?